# Postback fails on rare occasions

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webforms site built with the .NET framework 3.5. There is no jQUery, AJAX, or fancy code on this site - it was written by another developer a while back.

The page has a DropDownList that drives a DataList of questions the user needs to fill in. (Method names have been changed to protect the innocent)

**99.999% of the time, this code works just fine.** However, twice in the last four months, two users have reported the dataList doesn't populate on postback. They've selected the same value from the drop-down list, but efforts to reproduce the problem fail - the code always works fine locally, on dev, and on production for me.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstType" runat="server" DataTextField="Type" 
                        DataValueField="TypeID" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="lstType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers" runat="Server"
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RequestConn %>"
            SelectCommand="TypeQuestionsAndAnswers_Get" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            UpdateCommand="TypeQuestionsAndAnswers_Update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="ID" SessionField="RequestID" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lstType" Name="TypeID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gridTypeQuestionsAndAnswers" Name="AnswerID"
                    PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.values[&quot;AnswerID&quot;]" /> 
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Any errors showing up in the server's logs?

Comment: Could it be that the user is not waiting long enough for the server to respond? It could be difficult to track it down to the exact request, but if you have the [time-taken field](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884) enabled in the IIS logs you might get a hint.

Comment: The request usually completed in under a second. Well under a second - it's internal, with only a few dozen users (only one or two of which may be active at any given time). No errors on the server logs - it gets caught in the page error handling. I should note the error handling on this particular page is tough, because a lot of the code was drag + drop.

Comment: Do you have a code behind for this page?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman there is a code behind, but I don't want to post it because it's complex. It was written by someone who came before me, and modified several times. The problem is definitely coming from components that were originally dragged and dropped on the page (which makes error handling extremely difficult). I think it's time to consider tossing this code out and starting over.

Comment: Several possibilities come to mind: race condition between users (which is nearly impossible to find); NULL value in a column that was never expected; partially completed INSERT blocks; duplicated data. The partially completed INSERT blocks are particularly nasty because the code work most of the time. But they are easy to find. Look for some place where your code is doing a lot of INSERTs at once. If they aren't wrapped in a START TRANSACTION/COMMIT, add it.